# how to apply domain on One2many field in xml view in odoo 10?

Tags: python, odoo, postgresql-9.1

I am having records need to filter based on condition in xml view.

Model A (reg.customers):

```
field_a_id = fields.One2many('reg.customers', 'customer_id')
```

Model B (customers):

```
customer_id = fields.Many2one('customers')
status = fields.Selection([('option_a', 'Option A'), ('option_b', 'Option B')])
<separator string="Customers" colspan="4" /> 
   <group colspan="4" col="4">
       <field name="field_a_id" nolabel="1" >
          <tree delete="false" create="false">
              <field name="name" />
              <field name="father_name" />
              <field name="contact" />
              <field name="cnic" />
          </tree>
       </field>
   </group>
```

Comment: Could you please get in more detail? All three fields seem to belong to one model instead of two models. Do you mean that a model A has a one2many relation to another model B and that on the model A's form view, you want to filter those model B records by another field of model A?

Answer (score 0):

If I understood right I think that you would like to show inside a form view related to a certain customer_id a tree view with the values of field_a_id related to that customer_id.

If so, you may try to apply a domain filter to the field_a_id field, like:

```
<field name="field_a_id" domain="[('customer_id', '=', id)]" nolabel="1" options="{'no_create':True, 'no_delete': True}">
          <tree>
              <field name="name" />
              <field name="father_name" />
              <field name="contact" />
              <field name="cnic" />
          </tree>
</field>
```